# VirtualBox 6.0.4 with Linux 5.2 on Debian "testing"

Tags: debian, virtualbox

After a recent update, VirtualBox won't launch anymore. This is because I cannot compile the kernel module for Linux 5.2.0 on Debian "testing".

This is the output from trying to reconfigure the VirtualBox DKMS package:

```
# dpkg-reconfigure virtualbox-dkms

------------------------------
Deleting module version: 6.0.4
completely from the DKMS tree.
------------------------------
Done.
Loading new virtualbox-6.0.4 DKMS files...
Building for 5.2.0-2-amd64
Building initial module for 5.2.0-2-amd64
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.2.0-2-amd64 (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/6.0.4/build/make.log for more information.
```

The log contains the following error message:

```
/var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/6.0.4/build/vboxdrv/r0drv/linux/memobj-r0drv-linux.c:215:58: error: ‘MAP_SHARED’ undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean ‘VM_SHARED’?
          ulAddr = vm_mmap(NULL, R3PtrFixed, cb, fLnxProt, MAP_SHARED | MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_FIXED, 0);
                                                           ^~~~~~~~~~
                                                           VM_SHARED
```

Is there a solution?

Comment: Upgrade VB to v6.0.10.

Comment: This is not an answer, but VirtualBox was removed from Debian "stable" because package mantainers are unhappy with upstream's support for securiy fixes. Debian "testing" probably also won't get VirtualBox for the same reason. So either it will stay only on "unstable" or maybe on "fast-track" (once this is announced). Ref: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=794466

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [VirtualBox changelog](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Changelog), a version >=6.0.6 should be used. You can install the VirtualBox version for Debian-based Linux distributions from the [official site](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads).

I had the same issue and installing VirtualBox 6.0.12 for Linux solved this issue.